# HttpListener: chances of missing a message using while loop and BeginGetContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, httplistener

I'm afraid that there is space between one `BeginGetContext` and the next for a message to fly by unnoticed. Is that so?
Can receiving many requests simultaneously result into some of them being ignored?

```
Task.Run(() => {
    while (Not(CTok.IsCancellationRequested) && listener.IsListening) {
        IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(DoWork), listener);
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
});
```

```
private void DoWork(IAsyncResult willResult) {
   HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)willResult.AsyncState!;

   // Call EndGetContext to complete the asynchronous operation.
   HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(willResult);
   
   //do the actual work here, like parsing the content and building a response
}
```

It's the first time I'm using this `AsyncCallback/IAsyncResult` pattern, as well as using `HttpListener`,

On a separate note: if i run multiple listeners with prefixes that make them able to handle the same uri (`http://*.foo.com/` and  `http:/*.com/`) will just one run it's `AsyncCallback` or will both try to respond?

-EDIT-
switched to await/async, as it is available.

```
Task.Run(async () => {
    while (!(CTok.IsCancellationRequested) && StartedHttpListener.IsListening) {
    var ctx = await StartedHttpListener.GetContextAsync();
    _ = Task.Run(()=>Handler(ctx,CTok), CTok);
    //brief moment where no Context is being awaited/listened to, before the next loop iteration takes place
}
```

Is there any chance that this loop will miss a message, if multiple ones are received at the same time?

-ANSWER- by Panagiotis Kanavos
"..No request will be lost. Subsequent requests will wait until the iteration completes. .."

Comment: Why not use [GetContextAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.getcontextasync) instead? There's no reason to use `Begin...` methods when async methods are available. The pattern you try to use, [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm), was replaced by async/await in 2012. It wasn't used the way you tried either - your code is using `Task.Run` and CancellationToken classes that were introduced along with `async/await`.

Comment: Because on [HttpListener docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-6.0) the old approach is explained.  Is there one for the async/await approach?  
In fact i had to use some workaround with ```ManualResetEvent``` to allow for the ```AsyncHandle.Wait()``` cancellation.  
Await or not, i feel like a loop would still be involved and therefore the chance of there being a brief time where the listener is not, well, listening

Comment: So the *real* question is how to use a timeout. The docs you link to don't use BeginContentAsync anyway. If you find an old version that uses the APM methods it won't use `Task.Run` or cancellation tokens. You *can't* cancel an operation that doesn't accept a cancellation token, you can only stop waiting for it. Your current code doesn't stop listening after a while ,it tries to listen *again* while the previous operation is still active.

Comment: As the duplicate shows, you can use `await http.GetContextAsync().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),cancelToken.Token);` in all supported .NET Core versions (ie .NET 6 and up). In .NET Framework, or unsupported .NET Core versions, you can store the context task to a variable and use `await Task.WhenAny(ctxTask,Task.Delay(1000))` to wait for either the context task or the delay task to complete. `WhenAny` can be cancelled too, so you get both timeout and cancellation

Comment: You mean something like `while(!ct.IsCancellationRequest){ var ctx=await listener.GetContextAsync(); ProcessRequest(ctx); }` ? No request will be lost. Subsequent requests will wait until the iteration completes. That's not very performant though, which is why APIs and services use other threads to process requests. An easy way would be to use an `ActionBlock` to process the requests using a preconfigured number of threads.

Comment: The question is not about cancellation. I shouldn't have included the token part at all in the code. The question is: does looping over a GetContext guarantee that no request will be lost?  That said i appreciate the pointers, as with await/async it's much cleaner :)

Comment: It would be better if you explained what you actually want to do and why you don't use Minimal APIs. These eliminate the need to wait for requests and schedule request processing yourself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I indeed need just a simple way to receive Http POST request on a number of addresses, and respond either with StatusCode OK or BAD REQUEST. This is the simpler thing i found, any pointer will be much appreciated. (the POST requests hold JSON status updates i receive from an external API)

Comment: Did you check [Minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-code)? The relevant code is just `app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");`. JSON works out of the box so `app.MapGet("/todoitems", async (TodoDb db) =>await db.Todos.ToListAsync());` will serialize the response into JSON. `app.MapPost("/todoitems", async (Todo todo, TodoDb db) =>...` will serialize the request JSON into a `Todo` object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255575/discussion-between-andrea-bardelli-and-panagiotis-kanavos).